# Post to Facebook with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I have to post on a facebook page, the titles of articles (with link) posted on a blog.
Unfortunately I can only post the link, but without the title. How can I do?

The PHP code I am using is this:

```
   require ("facebook.php");
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
   'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
   'cookie' => true
   ));

   // id page
   $pageId = "136860079786056";
   // permanent session token
   $permSess = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

   // writing
   $test = $facebook->api(array(
   "uid" => $pageId,
   "method" => "stream.publish",
   "access_token" => $permSess,
   "message" => "http://www.mysite.it/functions.php?p=view&id=31", ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `link` variable you can use for the link.

Eg

```
"link" => "http://google.com",
"message" => "The search engine we can't mention"
```